# What types of plants can be used as treasure?

Tags: system-agnostic, treasure

I know there's amber, some rare woods for making armor and weapons, leaf armor, etc... but what other types of plants could be used as treasure?

Comment: Are you open to magical plants as well? 
This question might be better suited to [World Building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com)

Comment: yes I would... but not monsters. But if you wish to port the question to worldbuilding, feel free to do so.

Comment: @HarrisonSmith if you can tell me how to port it (without simply copying and pasting it there), that'd be appreciated

Comment: @JesseCohoon Question migration is performed by diamond moderators. However I don't believe this is a viable worldbuilding question in its current state, so we probably won't be migrating it. I suggest you look over their site's quality standards [and consider using their sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *Any* plant can be used as treasure

- The current price of [saffron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saffron#Trade), a food flavoring, is about
  USD2,200 per kg.
- [Truffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truffle) cost about USD1,500 per kg - although, technically, they are a fungus not a plant.
- In 17th century Amsterdam a [Semper Augustus](https://www.mnn.com/your-home/organic-farming-gardening/stories/7-of-the-most-expensive-flowers-in-the-world) tulip bulb was *advertised* for 10,000 guilders (several million dollars in today's currency). This was at the height of [tulip mania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip_mania) which is generally considered the first recorded speculative bubble but it goes to show that at the right time and the right place anything can be sold for ridiculous amounts.
- The [spice trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice_trade) in  cinnamon, cassia, cardamom, ginger, pepper, and turmeric (all plants) formed the basis of a world-spanning trade network and the interruption of the trade by the rise of Islam was the catalyst for the voyages of exploration that led to the world we know today.
- "[Pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_pepper#Production_and_trade) was so valuable that it was often used as collateral or even currency. In the Dutch language, "pepper expensive" (peperduur) is an expression for something very expensive. The taste for pepper (or the appreciation of its monetary value) was passed on to those who would see Rome fall. Alaric the Visigoth included 3,000 pounds of pepper as part of the ransom he demanded from Rome when he besieged the city in 5th century."
- [Cannabis](http://www.visualcapitalist.com/the-worlds-most-valuable-cash-crop/) is the world's most valuable crop per hectare under cultivation, worth over $47 million per km<sup>2</sup>. Making something illegal is a great way to drive up the price.

The value of *anything* depends on a complex interplay between utility, aesthetic, fashion, transport costs, desperation, risk and reward.